# start ros node without a launch file

Tags: roslaunch, roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to init and start a ros node as a service in an other framework to offer my data to an already existing data analysis software written in ROS. That means that this node is created within a non-ros process without a call of launch files.

So far I managed to call ros::init and create a nodeHandle etc. But I need to start any of rosnode first via roslaunch before my process get fully initialize (otherwise my process is blocked and waits for ROS). I guess roscore etc is missing.

How can I initialize all that within my own process, so that ROS gets fully set up without any call of roslaunch.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57848/start-ros-node-without-a-launch-file/) by [JohnnyRep](https://answers.ros.org/users/4400/johnnyrep/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-03-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just run `roscore` once somewhere else, and you should be good. You'll need to make sure that all of your ROS processes are launched with the proper `$ROS_MASTER_URI` environment variable so that they point to the machine on which you're running the roscore.

To learn more about how all this works, take a look at the [roscore wiki page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roscore).

---

Originally posted by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) with karma: 5809 on 2013-03-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2